# Difference between Map<String, String> and Map<>?

Tags: java, dictionary, objectinstantiation

What is he difference between two approaches of instantiating a map:

```
  Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
```

and

```
  Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

and which one is better?

Answer (score 11):

They are equivalent. The second syntax (known as the diamond operator) was added in Java 7 and allows you to type less code.

Comment: I have one more question why Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new TreeMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>() produces compile time error whilst Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new TreeMap<>() does not!

Comment: @DhaneshKhurana In `Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new TreeMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();` the assigned instance doesn't match the type of the variable. It should be `Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new TreeMap<String, Map<String, String>>();`